# matplotlib: outer stroke on inset axes ticklabels text

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an inset plot made using `fig.add_axes()`, and I want to add an outline to the existing text along both axes (both tick labels and to-be-added axis label text) to make it more readable over the background plot (a la "Outlined text" in the image below). Is there a direct method for doing this?

Excerpt:

```py
    inset_ax = fig.add_axes([0.20, 0.3, 0.5, 0.25], label='inset plot')
    inset_ax.plot(bp_locs, effs, color='black', linestyle='-')
    inset_ax.fill_between(
        bp_locs, effs-errors, effs+errors, alpha=0.25, edgecolor='black', 
        facecolor='gray', linewidth=1, linestyle='--', antialiased=True)
    inset_ax.set_xticks(bp_locs)
    inset_ax.set_xticklabels(bp_locs, rotation=60)
```

[image: outlined text example]

Comment: "outline to the existing text along both axes (both tick labels and to-be-added axis label text)".... unclear what you are trying to say. There is no "existing text". Outline to which text? Include a sample, even a hand-drawn sketch to explain what kind of final figure you want for the sake of clarity to the readers

Comment: @Sheldore I mean the existing tickmarks text (-1, -2, -3, etc.); will try to mock it up more clearly.